# How to remove a select option using Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, drop-down-menu, ecmascript-6, angular2-template

I am relatively new to angular2 / TS / ES6, I can not seem to find the answer to this anywhere.

I have a select with options that are dynamically rendered using ngFor, the options are in an array.
The select is meant for selecting options for a product. Once an option is selected, it gets pushed to another array that stores the products selected attributes. I would like the option removed from the DOM so it doesn't get in the users way, after it has been selected once.
I know I can disable it but I would really like to remove the option all-together.

Any help would be great.
I'm having trouble understanding how to manipulate the DOM with angular 2+

Comment: You can render options from another prop, say ''availableOptions", which is s slice of original array with options. When you push chosen option to another array also delete it in "availableOptions".

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the selected option try to remove it from original array. Which indeed re-render the drop-down menu. If directly modifying original array doesn't work then remove element and do something like this.

```
OriginalArray = Object.assign([],OriginalArray)
```